# Riak CS how to get list of all buckets and all files

Tags: riak, riak-cs

I was surprised to not find in documentation the answer on really simple questions:
How can I get the list of all buckets and all files in my Riak CS installation?
Also I need to have access to all those files in all buckets with some "root" account - how can I do that?

Anyway according to documentation: http://docs.basho.com/riakcs/latest/cookbooks/Account-Management/
A sample URL for a user listing request looks like this:

```
GET http://data.example.com/riak-cs/users -
or
s3curl --id admin -- http://data.mystorage.me/riak-cs/users
```

So, I've edited .s3crul:

```
%awsSecretAccessKeys = (
adminname => {
id => 'key here',
key => 'secret here',
},
);
```

and point s3curl directly to riak cs:

```
s3curl.pl --id adminname -- http://192.168.0.20:8080/riak-cs/users
```

Getting answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><Resource>/riak-cs/users</Resource><RequestId></RequestId></Error>
```

I'm sure that "adminname" is Admin account in Riak CS, I can see it in riac-cs-control panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems that you use custom host base, so what you have to do is to
tell it to `s3curl.pl`.  As you know, because S3 (or AWS v2)
authentication can be path style or subdomain style, `s3curl.pl` can
not use host part of URL or host header as is.  Therefore, it has some
hardcoded endpoints [1] for indentifing host base.

Some forks of `s3curl.pl` can specify the custom endpoint by option
argument [2]. If you setting `cs_root_host` as `data.mystorage.me`,
then the example command line looks like:

```
s3curl --id admin --endpoint data.mystorage.me \
    -- http://data.mystorage.me/riak-cs/users
```

or by subdomain style,

```
s3curl --id admin --endpoint data.mystorage.me \
    -- http://riak-cs.data.mystorage.me/users
```

Once you get all user information, you can do anything, e.g listing
buckets for certain user or listing all objects in certain bucket.

[1] https://github.com/ksauzz/s3curl/blob/master/s3curl.pl#L30-L34
[2] https://github.com/ksauzz/s3curl/blob/master/s3curl.pl#L121

Comment: The problem is in "Host" header:<br/>
`s3curl.pl --id admin --endpoint=my-data.example.com
http://192.168.0.20:8080/riak-cs/users`<br/>
Request:<br/>
GET /riak-cs/users HTTP/1.1<br/>
User-Agent: curl/7.41.0<br/>
Host: 192.168.0.20:8080<br/>
Accept: */*<br/>
Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2015 09:05:30 GMT<br/>
Authorization: AWS <aws key here>:<auth string here><br/>
Answer:<br/>
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

I still can't make it work thru proxy, but it is my problem already, direct connection to Riak CS with proper Host header and proper auth works for me. Thank you!

Comment: For proxy access, `-x` option of curl is helpful. `s3curl.pl --id admin -- -x 192.168.0.20:8080 http://my-data.example.com/riak-cs/users`

Answer (score 1):

For the listing part, try `s3cmd la -r s3://`

I don't think there is an account that has access to everything by default, you would have to add the account to each bucket's ACL

Comment: Thank you for "la -r"!
May be I can somehow retrieve list of all user keys and secrets? And I have to do this from script (not by opening webpage of riak-cs-control in browser using java script).